# org.json.JSONException: Value Email Already Exist at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio

i have a signup form which takes the username,email,password and mobile using json php and store them in php..but at runtime it is iving followin error.

> org.json.JSONException: Value Email Already Exist at 0 of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

my sinup.java is:

```
   package com.breera.automechanic_storeapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    EditText cusname,cusemail,cuspass,cusmobile,confrmpass;
    String cus_name,cus_email,cus_pass,cus_cnfrmPass,cus_mobile;
    Button btnlogin,btnSignup;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        cusname=findViewById(R.id.fn);
        cusemail=findViewById(R.id.cusemail);
        cuspass=findViewById(R.id.cuspass);
        cusmobile=findViewById(R.id.cusmobile);
        confrmpass=findViewById(R.id.confrmpass);



        btnlogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logbtn);
        btnSignup=findViewById(R.id.signup);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intnt=new Intent(Signup.this,CusLogin.class);
                startActivity(intnt);
            }
        });
        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "hhh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                onsignup();
            }
        });

    }public void onsignup(){
        cus_name = cusname.getText().toString();
        cus_email = cusemail.getText().toString();
        cus_pass = cuspass.getText().toString();
        cus_cnfrmPass=confrmpass.getText().toString();
        cus_mobile = cusmobile.getText().toString();


        try {
            UrlPassClasa urlPassClasa=new UrlPassClasa("customer/signup.php?name=" + cus_name +"&email=" + cus_email+ "&userpass=" + cus_pass+ "&cus_mobile=" + cus_mobile);


            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlPassClasa.getUrl(), null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Signup");
                                JSONObject signup = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                                int signupStatus = signup.getInt("status");
                               // String signupmsg = signup.getString("msg");

                                if (signupStatus == 1) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "han", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            mQueue.add(request);


        }//1st try
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(Signup.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }//end mthd
}
```

activity_signup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bck"
    tools:context=".Signup">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rider's Signup"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bck"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="10dp">



                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/input_layout_fn"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/fn"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp"

                            android:hint="Name"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:singleLine="true" />
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/cusemail"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:hint="Mail Address"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/cuspass"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
                        android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword" />



                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/confrmpass"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_open_black_24dp"
                         android:hint=" Confirm Password"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/cusmobile"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone_android_black_24dp"
                        android:hint=" Mobile No"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/logbtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:text="Already an account.Login" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/signup"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bck"
                    android:text="Sign up"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

signup.php:

```
<?php 
require_once("../includes/db.php");
require_once("../includes/functions.php");

$response["Signup"] = array();

$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$userpass = $_REQUEST["userpass"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["cus_mobile"];

//$name = "zain";
//$email = "zain@gmail.com";
//$userpass = "123";
//$phone = "123456";
$msg = array();

if (check_customer_email($con, $email)) {
    $msg["status"] = 0;
    $msg["msg"] = "Email Already Exist";
    array_push($response["Signup"], $msg["msg"]);

 }
else {
    $sql = "insert into customer(cus_name, cust_email, cust_userpass,cus_mobile) values ('$name', '$email', '$userpass','$phone')";
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        $msg["status"] = 1; 
        $msg["msg"] = "Values successfully Added";  
        array_push($response["Signup"], $msg["msg"]);
    }
    else {
        $msg["status"] = 0; 
        array_push($response["Signup"], $msg["status"]);
    }

}
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

UrlPassClasa.java:

```
package com.breera.automechanic_storeapp;

public class UrlPassClasa {
    String Url="http://192.168.0.107/auto_mechanic/";

    public UrlPassClasa(String file) {
        Url=Url+file;

    }
    public String getUrl(){
        return Url;

    }

}
```

database:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPhYQ.png)

Comment: `Value Email Already Exist at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`, could you.. dump the php response? i'm not really sure, but seems your android part did not read any other json apart from `{"Signup": {"msg": {"status": "xxx"}}}`.. but that error happens whenever you try to read the wrong json. ps. i also dont think the screenshot or the UI part relevant to your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your response inside a multidemnsional array in the way you are using it in the java code.

Right now you have basicly set the `signup` part of the json array to the value of

`"Email Already Exist"`

which is not valid json to be decoded.

This should do the trick: `in the php part`

```
if (check_customer_email($con, $email)) {
    $msg["status"] = 0;
    $msg["msg"] = "Email Already Exist";
    $response["Signup"][] = $msg;
}
else {
    $sql = "insert into customer(cus_name, cust_email, cust_userpass,cus_mobile) values ('$name', '$email', '$userpass','$phone')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $msg["status"] = 1;
    $msg["msg"] = "Values successfully Added";
    $response["Signup"][] = $msg;
}
else {
    $msg["status"] = 0;
    $response["Signup"][] = $msg;
}
```

The culprit in particular is this statement [and the ones like it in the code]

```
array_push($response["Signup"], $msg["status"]);
```

`$msg['status']` will be a plain string where you would want to make this value an array by not just assingning it one key [`"status"`] from the array.

Comment: i just made changes as you told and now its working...thanks sir...but i have still one confusion my same code is working for shopkeeper side but not here....i also didnt understand  the meaning of your this line "$msg['status'] will be a plain string where you would want to make this value an array by not just assingning it one key ["status"] from the array."

Comment: `msg[status]` has the value of "email already exists" and will not be converted to an jsonobject that can be decoded again.